# Is it correct to have nested Scaffold in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, scaffold, flutter-pageview, flutter-scaffold

I have a PageView in my app homepage and I want:

1. The AppBar changes according to the page
2. The BottomAppBar is fixed

The 2 solutions I imagined are:

1. The hard one: have one Scaffold with appBar, body and bottomNavigationBar; use the PageView's PageController to animate the AppBar content.
2. Have 2 nested Scaffold: the main one with body and bottomNavigationBar, and a second one in each PageView's page, with the AppBar.

So, I was wondering, it works, but is it "correct" syntactically to have nested Scaffolds?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html

There is a section named Troubleshooting and inside it, you will find this:

> **Nested Scaffolds**
>
> The Scaffold was designed to be the single top level container for a
> MaterialApp and it's typically not necessary to nest scaffolds. For
> example in a tabbed UI, where the bottomNavigationBar is a TabBar and
> the body is a TabBarView, you might be tempted to make each tab bar
> view a scaffold with a differently titled AppBar. It would be better
> to add a listener to the TabController that updates the AppBar.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did not see these guidelines. I choosed to keep one single Scaffold with body and bottom, and the body defines the AppBar in a Column. This option is much easier than animating the AppBar to follow the PageController...

Answer (score 1):

I think so.
Scaffold is just like any other widget imo.
It's just so convenient as it provides you with an app bar, body, etc.
I usually put it as a child of SafeArea widget so that the app takes into account the notches on the modern smartphones.